# Where can I go mud sliding in Europe (ideally the UK)?

Tags: uk, europe, activities, outdoor-activities

I've seen a number of videos on Youtube of people sliding down the muddy banks of the Shubenacadie river in Nova Scotia and it looks great fun. But I can't afford to travel to Nova Scotia.

Is there anywhere in Europe - even better if it's in the UK - where I can do something similar? My web searches for this tend to turn up a) muddy obstacle races, which sound a bit more intense and less "just messing about" than I'm looking for and b) stories of people being rescued after getting stuck in the mud! So where can I do something like this safely?

Comment: It would seem likely that if there was any mud sliding in the UK, it would also be captured on youtube. If you do a search on there you'll see various videos for "mud sliding uk". I suggest you browse those.

Answer (score 1):

It's most strange, I've spent the last 30 minutes searching (using advanced queries and location specific keywords) for places to mudslide in the UK and I can't seem to find anything. As you said there are plenty of mud runs, but no mud sliding to speak of. Perhaps you could contact a mud run host, and see if they will allow you to slide down a few hills for fun? Alternatively you could find any boggy hill in the countryside and pour a reasonable amount of water on it and slide down it...? I've done this before at Stafford castle.